# how to upload multiple image to aws s3 faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm using react-native-s3-upload library.

Right now, it's working well. but it's super slow.

I've used react-native-aws3. but there's no difference between them.

How can I make this faster than before?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < uploaded_file.length; i++) {
        let file = uploaded_file[i];
        let name =
          i == 0
            ? `${username}_${dtsuffix}.${file.name.split(".")[1]}`
            : `${username}_${dtsuffix}_${i + 1}.${file.name.split(".")[1]}`;
        file.name = name;
        let options = {
          keyPrefix: mediatype == "image" ? "images/" : "videos/",
          ...S3Options
        };

        try {

          let res = await RNS3.put(file, options);
          await console.log("RNS3 try 문", i);
          console.log(res);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
```

I guess for method takes time.

Is there any more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: you have various vars which dont need to be defined in the loop,, that would shave abit off, but I suspect you're talking about upload speed.. that depends on where you are uploading them from.

Comment: The reason vars is defined in the loop is because we need to make file name fit in our format.

Comment: what do you mean "uploading them from"? I'm using react-native

Comment: `options` is the same on each iteration from what I can see. Uploading them from your house/work using a local ISP may be slower than using say a VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: okay. you mean I'd better to upload image through VPS or server not local. is this right?

Comment: handle with backend

Comment: how can I handle that? I'm using library.